# Android: Unexpectedly Quit When Trying to Switch Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm new to posting, but have been using the site for help for a while now. So thanks for that!

I'm working on a new app, got everything running well. It's a kids' soundboard. 2 pages of imagebuttons in a relative layout, with onclick listeners which triggers SoundPool.

My question is this:

in testing I've discovered if you're finger is anywhere on the screen where a button is not (say pressing on the background) and then you try to touch a button (multitouch) ... the button press doesn't register. Any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: no, its not like that... there must be something else in your app

Answer (score 1):

You have to cover additional event types for multi-touch, if you are not covering below Actions, you are not covering multi-touch

**MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:** This event happens for any additional finger that
touches the screen after the first finger touches

**MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP**:This gets
fired when a finger is lifted up from the screen and more than one finger is touching
the screen.

The explanation is quite tedious. I suggest you to google multi-touch for android. One helpful link is: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html